# OpenShift :: POD is not inheriting "name label" from the deployment config

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openstack

1. I created a build config from the git repo (Docker based app).

   `oc new-build <git-url> --name=myApp`
2. Created a deployment config using:

   `oc create dc myApp --image=<image-stream-repo>`

I am adding labels to this deployment config from the UI.

3. Now when I deploy the application (from the UI) or use `oc rollout`, the POD is created and the application is running in the POD.

**But the label (name: myApp) is not being applied to the POD.** As a result the `selector` in the `service` is failing to identify the POD. The service is configured with label `name: myApp` as POD selector.

If I go to the created POD and `edit yaml` and add `name: myApp` in the `labels` section, only then the POD is being identified by the service.

In case if any one has faced similar issue, please provide your inputs in overcoming this problem.

Comment: Instead of ``oc create dc``, use ``oc new-app myApp``, or being more explicit, ``oc new-app --image-stream myApp``. Note that the name has to be all lower case.

Comment: There is rarely a need to create a ``dc`` explicitly using ``oc create`` like you are. If you use ``oc new-app`` to deploy the image, it will create the service with appropriate labels for you.

Comment: If you haven't already, suggest you read the free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/

Answer (score 1):

To set a label on a `Pod` using a `DeploymentConfig`, the label must be placed in a much more deeply nested key, as shown below, or else it will be set on the `DeploymentConfig` itself, not the `Pod`:

```
objects:
  - kind: DeploymentConfig
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: my-name
      # labels: NOT HERE (FOR DC ONLY)!
    spec:
        replicas: 1
        selector:
          app: my-name
        strategy:
          type: Rolling
        template:
          metadata:
            labels:
              app: my-name
              myAppsGroup: myApp
```

You can verify the correctness of pod labeling using `oc describe pod my-name`